# go still run even its path not in environment variable path?

Tags: snap, environment-variables, golang

I install go by snap, the path to executable file of go is not in environment variable path, but when I use

```
go run test.go
```

in terminal (from my home directory), go still work.

As my understand, the path to executable file of go must in environment variable path, so linux can find where it is and run it. In this case, how Linux find where executable file of go is?

Here is my path variable (in file /etc/environment)

> PATH="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games"

And here is path to executable file of go:

> /snap/go/3095/bin/

I use linux mint xfce 18.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your actual $PATH is probably different than the on in `/etc/environment`. Check this by typing `echo $PATH` in the terminal. It probably includes `/snap/bin`, and this directory probably has a symbolic link to the `go` executable. I have Ubuntu rather than Linux Mint, but on my system the $PATH gets updated by `/etc/profile.d/apps-bin-path.sh` with this line:

```
export PATH=$PATH:${snap_bin_path}
```

Comment: After `echo $PATH`, I see /snap/bin, but the symbolic link not point to `go` executable, it point to usr/bin/snap. Here, snap is shared library file (I see it when check properties of this file); so what is the shared library file? What is its role, here?

Comment: @ydhhat - It would be helpful to see more details, such as the full path of the `go` symbolic link and the full path that it points to. I don't know the internals of the `snap` system, but an executable can see the filename that was used to run it, even if it was a symbolic link. One possibility is that the snap shared library file executes the `go` snap when it sees that it was launched with a `go` symlink.

Comment: the full path of the go symbolic link is `/snap/bin/go`, and the full path that the symbolic link point to is `usr/bin/snap`

Comment: I create a new question about how this shared library file work. Check out at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109351/how-shared-libary-file-snap-help-ubuntu-find-the-path-of-go-executable-file

Comment: @ydhhat - Thanks for the additional information. I think it was a good choice to create a separate question about what `/usr/bin/snap` does and why it's set up that way. So for this question, is it fully answered?

Comment: The link of the question is in the above comment.

Comment: @ydhhat - Sorry to be unclear; I was asking about **this** question ([question 1109069](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109069) )